# angular 2 ng2-datetime-picker shows 6 column

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, ng2-datetime

ng2-datetime-picker shows 6 columns, so days are invalid. Saturday is under Sunday, check image.

[ng2-datetime-picker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Nlks.png)
my code looks like this:

```
<input date-format="DD-MM-YY" ng2-datetime-picker date-only="true" 
   class="" [(ngModel)]="newDate" (valueChanged)="dateChange($event)" />
```

I tried to increase with off outer div and width of this input. won't help. Couldn't find this problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    .ng2-datetime-picker {
        width: 235px;
    }

    .days {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
```

this helped, but still don't know what caused this problem.